# OAuth 2.0 Azure Active Directory <> next-auth

Tags: azure, oauth-2.0, azure-active-directory

I'm trying to use the next-auth library to call Azure Active Directory via OAuth 2.0, but not sure how to go about doing this.

The providers format in my /api/[...nextauth].js is currently:

```
providers: [
{
    id: 'azure',
    name: 'Azure Active Directory',
    type: 'oauth',
    version: '2.0',
    scope: 'read',
    accessTokenUrl: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{directory_id}/oauth2/v2.0/token',
    authorizationUrl: 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/{directory_id}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize',
    clientId: process.env.OAUTH_APP_ID,
    clientSecret: process.env.OAUTH_APP_PASSWORD,
  },
```

This doesn't seem to be working (Error: "The reply URL specified in the request does not match the reply URLs configured for the application:"). How should I go about this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm quite late with my answer, but for the sake of this question being answered:

Usually, this message means that you're missing the right redirect URI.
In Azure, open your app registration, go to Authentication and enter the redirect URI under "Single-page application".

In this case, it's going to be something like `http://localhost/api/auth/callback/azure` for your local development.